# Django: passing a filtered Queryset to a ListView?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Using Django Class Based Views, I already have a `ListView` for `Order` objects, and I created a `FormView` to perform advanced searches on these orderers.

However, I'm not sure how to pass the filtered queryset of the `FormView` to the `ListView`.

Here is the code, with commented sections to explain the issue:

```
class OrdersListView(PermissionRequiredCanHandleOrders,
                     SelectRelatedMixin, PrefetchRelatedMixin,
                     ModelInContextMixin, SubSectionLastOrders,
                     RestaurantOrdersOnly,
                     ListView):
    model = Order
    paginator_class = DiggPaginator
    paginate_by = 15
    select_related = ('convive__user',)
    prefetch_related = ('orderoperation_set',)
    # will use the template named order_list.html


class OrdersAdvancedSearchView(PermissionRequiredCanHandleOrders,
                               ModelInContextMixin, SubSectionLastOrders,
                               RestaurantOrdersOnly, RestaurantMixin,
                               FormView):
    model = Order
    template_name = "orders/order_advanced_search.html"
    form_class = OrderAdvancedSearchForm


    def form_valid(self, form):

        data = form.cleaned_data
        queryset = Order.objects.all()

        # Here, I'm using the form content to filter the queryset
        # queryset = queryset.filter(some_attribute__in=data['stuff'])

        # MY PAIN POINT IS HERE: what I'm supposed to do here ?
        # my queryset is filtered, and I need to call OrderListView 
        # with it.

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Use `class class_name(View):` and define `def get(self, request):` and `def post(self, request);` methods inside of it. That is defined in `from django.views import View` take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views

Comment: @Ahtisham May I ask you some sample code with the case I provided?  Note that I want to keep the `OrdersListView` as is. I changed the title of the question to be more explicit about my issue.

Comment: If all you want is filtering a `ListView` which is what it sounds like, there's no need to POST a form (POST is usually to modify data in the database). Why can't your HTML page GET the same ListView with the search parameters as query parameters in the URL? That way you only need to process the GET parameters in the `get_queryset()` method of your `ListView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `ListView` to filter the queryset with the `GET` request parameters. For this, add the form to your context and process it when getting the queryset:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    self.form = OrderAdvancedSearchForm(data=self.request.GET or None)
    if self.request.GET and form.is_valid():
        # filter using the form's cleaned_data
        queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(...)
    else:
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
    return queryset

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  # this calls self.get_queryset() which assigns self.form
    context['form'] = self.form
    return context
```

Now in your template you can just render the same form, except its method should be "GET" not "POST".

Comment: Note: Since you're using two different templates, one for a simple view and one for an 'advanced' filtered view, you could override the `get_template_names` method to select a template depending on what the user chooses to see (adding a query parameter to the URL or having two different URLs pointing to the same view, but adding a `kwargs` argument to one of them). But you could solve that inside one template as well (showing/hiding the advanced form with javascript).

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten it helped a lot :)